# msysGit on 64-bit Windows 7

Tags: git, 64-bit

I'm new to  git, but after attempting to get more information using `$git help [command_name]`, it says "launching default browser to display HTML...", but nothing happens.

Since installing Win7 64-bit, I've noticed issues with lower level drivers, but not so much with applications.

Any known issues with Win7 64-bit and `Git-1.7.0.2-preview20100309.exe`?

gracias

Comment: The command you mentioned works for me, there must be something else interfering with it. Also there's newer version you can install (1.7.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the [currently opened issues with msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/list) mentions such a problem.

As mention in [this old bug](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=36&can=1&q=help&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Component%20Owner%20Summary), you can check if the help html files are there or not, but I bet the right files are in the right place with recent msysgit distro.

---

The [issue 187](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=187&can=1&q=help&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Component%20Owner%20Summary) is similar to your problem, and reports an issue with:

- the Chrome browser
- and/or html association files:

> For me on Windows XP the problem was missing `.html` file type extensions.
>   I downloaded [Doug Knox's "HTM/HTML Associations" registry fix](http://dougknox.com/xp/file_assoc.htm).

---

The [issue 258](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=258&can=1&q=help&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Component%20Owner%20Summary) does report a problem under x64 system, when your installation path includes spaces:

> It seems the `start` command even when launched natively from `cmd.exe` will mess up when
>   the target path has spaces in it.
>   If we ensure that the title argument is provided then it succeeds

```
 start "c:/A B/c.html" fails to open in browser
 start "browser" "c:/A B/c.html" succeeds
```

> The bash equivalent is therefore

```
 start '"browse"' "$@"
```

> So the correct fix is going to be to leave start alone and change how we call it in
>   web-browser. The attached patch should do the job I think.